# Why are my Z-index's failing to adjust and how do I adjust my code to have my container properly control all nested elements?

Tags: html, css

- im trying to use `class="yoda-main"` as my wrapper/container but centering it does not center all elements within
- the `class="yoda-head"` element and nested elements reacts to the page being adjusted but the 'class="yoda-body"' and its nested elements do not. I'm looking for the `class="yoda-head"` and `class="yoda-body"` to act/move as one.
- when the page is split in half or adjusted to fit different places of the screen, the `"yoda-body"` remains in the middle and doesn't adjust to the page
- another issue I had was my z-index classes didn't appear to be working with the hand and arm classes.

What I've attempted after Reviewing Questions:

- used main as a container `class="yoda-main"` then set position to relative and width to 100%, did not work
- tried using `class="yoda-head"` as wrapper/container

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: #c9d2fc;
}

.yoda-main {
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
}

.yoda-head {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #009900 85%,#00CC33 100%);
    width: 305px;
    height: 225px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 45%;
    z-index: 3;
    display: flex;
}

.yoda-left-ear {
    position: absolute;
    top: -85px;
    left: -133px;
    z-index: 1;
    border-top-right-radius: 90px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-left: 85px solid transparent;
    border-right: 80px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 300px solid #009900;
    border-radius: 0 100em 100em 0;
    padding: 10px;
    transform: rotate(-75deg);
    z-index: 2;
}

.yoda-left-inner-ear {
    position: absolute;
    top: 65px;
    left: -33px;
    border-top-right-radius: 90px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-left: 35px solid transparent;
    border-right: 30px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 125px solid #d89680;
    border-radius: 0 100em 100em 0;
    padding: 10px;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    z-index: 3;
}

.yoda-right-ear {
    position: absolute;
    top: -85px;
    left: 270px;
    z-index: 1;
    border-top-right-radius: 90px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-left: 85px solid transparent;
    border-right: 80px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 300px solid #009900;
    border-radius: 0 100em 100em 0;
    transform: rotate(75deg);
    z-index: 2;
}

.yoda-right-inner-ear {
    position: absolute;
    top: 65px;
    left: -45px;
    border-top-right-radius: 90px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-left: 35px solid transparent;
    border-right: 30px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 125px solid #d89680;
    border-radius: 0 100em 100em 0;
    padding: 10px;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    z-index: 3;
}

.yoda-left-eye {
    position: absolute;
    top: 45px;
    left: 75px;
    border-radius: 60%;
    width: 40px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #000;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    z-index: 4;
}

.yoda-right-eye {
    position: absolute;
    top: 45px;
    left: 180px;
    border-radius: 60%;
    width: 40px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #000;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    z-index: 4;
}

.yoda-left-inner-eye {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 11px;
    height: 18px;
    width: 8px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 60%;
    transform: rotate(-25deg);
    z-index: 5;
}

.yoda-right-inner-eye {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 11px;
    height: 18px;
    width: 8px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 60%;
    transform: rotate(-25deg);
    z-index: 5;
}

.yoda-nose {
    position: absolute;
    top: 95px;
    left: 133px;
    border-left: 15px solid transparent;
    border-right: 15px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid #005700;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
    border-top-left-radius: 50%;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    z-index: 5;
}

.yoda-smile {
    position: absolute;
    top: 93px;
    left: 100px;
    width: 35%;
    height: 25%;
    background-color: #009900;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border-bottom: solid 3px #000;
    bottom: 30px;
    z-index: 4;
}

.yoda-scarf {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    width: 300px;
    top: 715px;
    left: 1135px;
    background-color: #fdd0a6;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 3px solid #cc9569;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #cc9569;
    z-index: 2;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.yoda-body {
    position: absolute;
    top: 675px;
    left: 1111px;
    height: 440px;
    width: 350px;
    background-color: #d8aa85;
    border-top-right-radius: 65%;
    border-top-left-radius: 65%;
    border: 8px solid #cc9569;
    z-index: 1;
}

.yoda-body-strap1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 155px;
    left: 5px;
    background-color: #cc9569;
    height: 40px;
    width: 395px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    border-top-right-radius: 90%;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 25%;
    border: 2px solid #be8b61;
    z-index: 3;
}

.yoda-body-strap2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 300px;
    left: -8px;
    background-color: #cc9569;
    height: 40px;
    width: 345px;
    border: 2px solid #be8b61;
    border-top-right-radius: 30%;
    z-index: 3;
}

.yoda-arm-left {
    position: absolute;
    height: 75px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #d8aa85;
    left: -135px;
    top: 113px;
    border: 8px solid #be8b61;
    border-right: 0px solid transparent;
    transform: rotate(35deg);
    z-index: 2;
}

.yoda-arm-right {
    position: absolute;
    height: 75px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: #d8aa85;
    left: 275px;
    top: 220px;
    transform: rotate(50deg);
    border: 8px solid #be8b61;
    border-left: 0px solid transparent;
    z-index: 2;
}

.yoda-hand-left {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #009900;
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: -25px;
    left: -55px;
    border-top-right-radius: 70%;
    border-top-left-radius: 70%;
    border: 2px solid #005700;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    z-index: 1;
}

.yoda-hand-right {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #009900;
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: -30px;
    left: 110px;
    border-top-right-radius: 70%;
    border-top-left-radius: 70%;
    border: 2px solid #005700;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    z-index: 1;
}

.yoda-finger1 {
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    height: 70px;
    width: 17px;
    top: 50px;
    left: -5px;
    background-color: #009900;
    border: 2px solid #005700;
    border-top-right-radius: 50%;
    border-top-left-radius: 65%;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20%;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 60%;
    border-top: 0px solid transparent;
}

.yoda-finger2 {
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    height: 75px;
    width: 17px;
    top: 70px;
    left: 30px;
    background-color: #009900;
    border: 2px solid #005700;
    border-top: 0px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20%;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 60%;
    border-top-left-radius: 65%;
    border-top-right-radius: 50%;
}

.yoda-finger3 {
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    height: 75px;
    width: 17px;
    top: 70px;
    left: 60px;
    background-color: #009900;
    border: 2px solid #005700;
    border-top: 0px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20%;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 60%;
    border-top-left-radius: 65%;
    border-top-right-radius: 50%;
}

.yoda-finger4 {
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    height: 70px;
    width: 17px;
    top: 40px;
    left: 90px;
    background-color: #009900;
    border: 2px solid #005700;
    border-top: 0px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20%;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 60%;
    border-top-left-radius: 65%;
    border-top-right-radius: 50%;
    transform: rotate(-5deg);
}

.yoda-finger5 {
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    width: 17px;
    top: 60px;
    left: 80px;
    background-color: #009900;
    border: 2px solid #005700;
    border-top: 0px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20%;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 60%;
    border-top-left-radius: 65%;
    border-top-right-radius: 50%;
    transform: rotate(5deg);
}

.yoda-finger6 {
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    width: 17px;
    top: 65px;
    left: 55px;
    background-color: #009900;
    border: 2px solid #005700;
    border-top: 0px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20%;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 60%;
    border-top-left-radius: 65%;
    border-top-right-radius: 50%;
}

.yoda-finger7 {
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    width: 17px;
    top: 65px;
    left: 27px;
    background-color: #009900;
    border: 2px solid #005700;
    border-top: 0px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20%;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 60%;
    border-top-left-radius: 65%;
    border-top-right-radius: 50%;
}

.yoda-finger8 {
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    width: 17px;
    top: 55px;
    left: -4px;
    background-color: #009900;
    border: 2px solid #005700;
    border-top: 0px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20%;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 60%;
    border-top-left-radius: 65%;
    border-top-right-radius: 50%;
    transform: rotate(-5deg);
}

.ball1 {
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left: 15%;
    background-color: grey;
    height: 275px;
    width: 275px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    opacity: 100%;
}

.ball2 {
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 13%;
    background-color: grey;
    height: 245px;
    width: 245px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    opacity: 45%;
}

.ball3 {
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    top: 70%;
    left: 10%;
    background-color: grey;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    opacity: 33%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <title>CSS Baby Yoda</title>
    </head>    
    <body>
        <main class="yoda-main">
            <div class="ball1"></div>
            <div class="ball2"></div>
            <div class="ball3"></div>
            <div class="yoda-head">
                <div class="yoda-ears">
                    <div class="yoda-left-ear">
                        <div class="yoda-left-inner-ear"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="yoda-right-ear">
                        <div class="yoda-right-inner-ear"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="yoda-eyes">
                        <div class="yoda-left-eye">
                            <div class="yoda-left-inner-eye"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="yoda-right-eye">
                            <div class="yoda-right-inner-eye"></div>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="yoda-nose"></div>
                <div class="yoda-smile"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="yoda-scarf"></div>
            
            <div class="yoda-body">
                <div class="yoda-body-strap1"></div>
                <div class="yoda-body-strap2"></div>

                <div class="yoda-arm-left">
                    <div class="yoda-hand-left">
                        <div class="yoda-finger1"></div>
                        <div class="yoda-finger2"></div>
                        <div class="yoda-finger3"></div>
                        <div class="yoda-finger4"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="yoda-arm-right">
                    <div class="yoda-hand-right">
                        <div class="yoda-finger5"></div>
                        <div class="yoda-finger6"></div>
                        <div class="yoda-finger7"></div>
                        <div class="yoda-finger8"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello! I've been learning to code for a little over a month, I noticed that my z-indexes specifically with each hand and arm div don't adjust when values are changed. My main issue is that the 'class=yoda-head' element and its nested elements adjust when the screen size is changed, whereas any other element does not.